# show title of the page in tab of browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, browser

I have created a website in MVC4 and i want to show the title of my page in the Browser tab instead of the URL of browser. Please let me know what exactly needs to be done.
Please click on below URL for references:-
http://incubatizealpha.azurewebsites.net/User/Login

Comment: Hello @17Coder. You aren't improving formatting by turning the whole post into a block quote. Please only use block quotes on _actual quotes_. For more details, see our editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Good job on spotting that invalid edit @Jongware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow default routine for displaying title in ASP.NET MVC.

in _Layout.cshtml

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Your SiteName | @ViewBag.Title</title>
        .
        .
```

in other pages just set `ViewBag.Title`. for example login page

```
@model LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login page";
}
```